# TLS version not set correctly, can't pull session info

Tags: c++, openssl, libcurl

**RESOLVED**

Build configuration error.

The officially "blessed" implementations of curl and OpenSSL on our system are *woefully* out of date (OpenSSL 0.9.8).  All the applications I communicate with won't accept anything below TLS v1.2, so I had downloaded and built OpenSSL 1.1 and Curl 7.48 under my home directory.

However, even though I specified `--with-ssl=/my/tools/ssl` in the `configure` command for building Curl, it was still picking up the old version of libssl under /etc/lib.

I had to do the following to get everything to build Curl properly:

```
#
# make sure prefix in /my/tools/lib/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc is set to
# /my/tools
#
CFG_PACKAGE_PATH=/my/tools/lib/pkgconfig:$CFG_PACKAGE_PATH
CPPFLAGS="-I/my/tools/include"
LDFLAGS="-L/my/tools/lib/"

./configure --prefix=/my/local --with-ssl
```

After that, Curl properly linked against my local OpenSSL build and worked correctly.

**ORIGINAL**

Particulars-

```
OS: SLES 10
Compiler: g++ 4.1.2
libcurl: 7.48.0
OpenSSL: 1.0.21
```

We have a C++ application that's using libcurl to connect to a URL through OpenSSL.  I'm getting an SSL connect error because, according to the admin of the remote site, we're trying to connect with TLS 1.0, which they have disabled.  However, I'm explicitly setting the protocol to TLS version 1.2 in my code as follows:

```
if ( curl_easy_setopt( m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2 ) != CURLE_OK)
  m_log.logv( LOG_ERR, "%s - Cannot set SSL version to TLS 1.2!", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
```

I don't get the error message, so the SSL version *should* be set to TLS 1.2, but for some reason it gets sent out as TLS 1.0.

I'm trying to pull session information to try to verify that things are set the way I think, so I'm using the `curl_easy_getinfo` function, but it's returning an error code of CURLE_BAD_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT.  I've gone over my call against the CURL documentation, and as far as I can tell I'm passing the things it expects.

Here's the meat of the code (not the *exact* code, but the order of operations and calls themselves reflect it accurately):

```
CURL *m_curlHandle;
...
curl_global_init( CURL_GLOBAL_ALL );
m_curlHandle = curl_easy_init( ) ;

curl_easy_setopt( m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0" );
curl_easy_setopt( m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1 );
curl_easy_setopt( m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
curl_easy_setopt( m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_POST, 1L );
curl_easy_setopt( m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 );
curl_easy_setopt( m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L );
curl_easy_setopt( m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, &m_curlErrBuffer );
curl_easy_setopt( m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data );
curl_easy_setopt( m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_data );
curl_easy_setopt( m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1 );
...
if ( curl_easy_setopt( m_curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2 ) != CURLE_OK)
  m_log.logv( LOG_ERR, "%s - Cannot set SSL version to TLS 1.2!", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
...
struct curl_tlssessioninfo *session;
CURLcode result;

result = curl_easy_getinfo( m_curlHandle, CURLINFO_TLS_SSL_PTR, &session );
```

Based on the documentation [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLINFO_TLS_SSL_PTR.html), I'm passing the right arguments to `curl_easy_getinfo`, so this is becoming especially frustrating.

Anyone have *any* ideas on a) how I can verify that I'm using TLS 1.2 or not on outgoing messages, and 2) how I can pull session information correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"... but for some reason it gets sent out as TLS 1.0..."* - We probably need to see a Wireshark trace, but... There are two versions in play. First is the record layer version, and second is the TLS version used in handshake and subsequently cipher selection and bulk encryption. Also see [TLS Client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki. The images on the right show you the fields, like the TLS handshake version.